# Why is it possible to use Android Support v4 on an Android 4.0.3 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin.android

Being quite new to the Android Platform I'm a bit suprised that it is possible to use the Android v4 Support Library on a x86 HAXM Emulator image (API Level 15) that is configured for Target "Android 4.0.3 - API Level 15". I thought the support library is only supported if the emulator image targets "Google APIs - API Level 15".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android v4 Support Library supports all Android OS above 4 (Android 1.6), the same goes for the v7 (Android 2.1) and v11 (Android 3.0) version of the support library. The functions these support libraries use are *not* tied to Google services, so you do not need to target images with Google services built in (i.e. "Google APIs - API Level 15").

If your app uses Google Play services, however, you would need to target "Google APIs - API Level 15".